# Problems installing Cinelerra

Tags: cinelerra

bonjour,

J' ai essayer par tous les moyens pour installer cinelerra par internet, par le terminal je n' arrive pas à installer cinelerra !
Pouvez-vous m' aider.

merci

---

Hello,

I have tried to install Cinelerra both through the internet and the terminal, but I have not been successful. Can you please help me!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cinelerra is not available through Ubuntu's default repositories. You have to add their ppa to your sources before you can install it.

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

Cinelerra should now be installed on your system.

---

Cinelerra n'est pas disponsible par les repositories défaut d'Ubuntu. Il faut que vous ajouter les PPA de Cinelerra à votre sources avant que vous l'intallez.

Utilisez ces commandement dans le terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

Cinelerra devra maintenant être installé sur votre system.